# Disable 31 from dateedit if the selected month doesn't have it?

Tags: vb.net, date, devexpress

i have dateedit from devexpress. the thing is, when i arrow up the date to `31 april` and then lost focus the date section the dateedit value change to `31 jan`. the cause of this is april didnt have `31` and the dateedit mask is `dd MMM yyy` which make user can change date from `1` to `31`.
what i want is:

1. disable 31 if the month didnt have date 31, especially `febuary`
2. or if the date edit reach the end of date, then the month change to next month. e.g `30 april` then when i arrow up it change to `1 may`
3. or maybe another approach of this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q584092) this is by design. However, there is a [workaround](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachmentFile/28b2f40f-be67-11e3-bf01-60a44c7179fa).
You have to set editors mask type to RegEx and validate the value manually.

Excerpt from the sample:

```
dateEdit3.Properties.Mask.MaskType = MaskType.RegEx;
dateEdit3.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "([012]?[1-9]|[123]0|31)/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/([123][0-9])?[0-9][0-9]";
dateEdit3.Validating += dateEdit3_Validating;
dateEdit3.ParseEditValue += dateEdit3_ParseEditValue;

.......

void dateEdit3_ParseEditValue(object sender, ConvertEditValueEventArgs e) {
   e.Handled = true;
}

 void dateEdit3_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
    DateEdit de = sender as DateEdit;
    DateTime temp;
    e.Cancel = !DateTime.TryParseExact(de.Text, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out temp);
 }
```